# Excel Userform: Combobox used to populate text or list box

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Excel VBA: I am working on combobox and i need to populate the information in textbox or listbox. Combobox takes value from column E (E contains date that are repeated). So combobox must contain unique values. Then in listbox, i want information in corresponding row. 
E.g. If in column E, 1 to 10 October dates where 5 to 10 October is two times. So i want combobox to take unique dates i.e. 1 to 10 October. If  i select 7 October, then in listbox it should show me data of two entries corresponding to 7 October date. More over, the fields i need are in column G,J,K,L,M column.
If it is possible to visualize it differently in userform then please suggest.

I was working on following code.

```
'=========================================================================================

'For collecting unique value in userform combobox
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    UserForm2.ComboBox1.Clear

Dim v, e
With Sheets("Atorvastatin").Range("E2:E1000")
    v = .Value
End With

With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    .comparemode = 1
    For Each e In v
        If Not .exists(e) Then .Add e, Nothing
    Next
    If .Count Then Me.ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
End With

    Set xRg = Sheets("Atorvastatin").Range("E2:Q1000")

End Sub

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim var1 As Long
    Me.TextBox1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1.Value, xRg, 3, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: you'd better add some more explanations and/or examples of your actual and expected results

Comment: I want combobox to take unique dates from column E and have detailed view of corresponding cells in userform.

Answer (score 0):

to fill `ListBox1` you can use the following code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim f As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    Set f = xRg.Find(what:=Me.ComboBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) ' always specify at least 'LookIn' and 'LookAt' parameters, or they will be set as per last 'Find()' usage (even from Excel UI!)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then ' if a match found
        With Me.ListBox1 
            '.Clear ' uncomment to have ListBox1 filled with elements corresponding with current ComboBox1 selected element only
            firstAddress = f.Address ' store first matched cell address
            Do
                .AddItem f.Offset(, 2).Value ' add currently matched cell2 columns to the right value 
                Set f = xRg.FindNext(f) ' search for next occurrence
            Loop While f.Address <> firstAddress ' exit do when hitting first found cell again
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

This way it'd suffice setting `xRG` to column E only

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.ComboBox1.Clear

    Dim v, e
    With Sheets("Atorvastatin") 
        With .Range("E2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
            Set xRg = .Cells ' set xRG to column E range only
            v = .Value
        End With
    End With

    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        .comparemode = 1
        For Each e In v
            If Not .exists(e) Then .Add e, Nothing
        Next
        If .Count Then Me.ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your help. lsitbox is still not getting populated.

Comment: I want combobox to take unique dates value from column E. Then using vlookup (or other function) i want corresponding cell value from column G, J, K, L, M to populate in textbox or listbox.

Comment: you are welcome. in my test ListBox1 did get populated, so step through your code (press F8 to highlight current codeline to be executed) and see what's happening (e.g.: use immediate window - CTRL-G to pop it out - and query relevant variables)

Comment: in your question you wrote _"...while list or textbox can take multiple selection from column M"_ and now you're saying _"i want corresponding cell value from column G, J, K, L, M"_: is it a game?

Comment: thanks for prompt reply. but i did not get what you have mentioned. I tried above thing, but in immediate window nothing is coming.

Comment: i want to build for one cell, then i thought of building the model for other cells.thats why mentioned G,J,K,L,M column

Comment: my code is for one cell, as per your question: go and see if it works. if it doesn't, then explain what doesn't work exactly. if it does, please mark the answer as accepted and, for new issues start a new question

Comment: it is taking unique value from column E, but in listbox nothing is shown. at the same time, it is not giving any error.

Comment: listbox is being filled with `f.Offset(, 2).Value` values, where `f` is a cell in column "E" of sheet "Atorvastatin" -> is being filled from column G values of sheet "Atorvastatin": if you want  to get values from a different column of that sheet then just use a different column offset (e.g.: `f.Offset(, 8).Value` for column "M")